# STM32F7 Discovery USB CDC using CubeMX

Tags: serial, usb-device, usb-otg, stm32cubemx, stm32f7

I've created a project in CubeMX for my F7 Discovery. I followed instructions form [here](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F33549084%2Fstm32cubemx-usb-cdc-vcp&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNEc0v3pXZNXuy-v93FyL4OjJ22iXw). However, in my Device Manager on Windows nothing appears. When I used precompiled code from [link](http://stm32f4-discovery.com) I was assured drivers installed on Windows works properly. MCU after checking this: `if( hUsbDevice_0 ==NULL)` returns from the function. What's wrong? Maybe I should use another function to enable something in USB module on MCU?

Answer (score 1):

It's a pity that STMicroelectronics does not include clock enable code in their libraries. The solution is to enable USB OTG clock by calling `__HAL_RCC_USB_OTG_FS_CLK_ENABLE();` in a `MX_USB_DEVICE_Init()` routine or before.

Answer (score 1):

That's because from stm32f4-discovery link you gave, precompiled hex file has enabled USB clock and also PLL configuration is properly set to ensure 48MHz is enabled for USB, if you are using USB FS MODE.

In USB HS mode with external PHY, you don't need to take care about clock so much since clock reference is from PHY chip.

And let me introduce myself. My name is Tilen and I'm owner of that site you posted a link.

Have a nice day.

Comment: This is true, and as I discovered, the HAL does a very weak job of verifying that clocks are valid... rather it prefers to just silently fail under certain conditions.